# the version angular catch

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a probleme with my angular project version 6. I must write this code in version Angular6.

What is wrong, thans for yours helps

**Version Angular4**

```
login(user: User){

   let url = 'http://localhost:3000/login';
   return this.http.post<any>(url, user).map(res => {
     this.guardStorage(res.id, res.token, res.user, res.menu);
       return true;
     }).catch(error => {
       console.log(err);
       return Observable.throw(err);
   });
}
```

**Version Angular6**

```
login(user: User){

   let url = 'http://localhost:3000/login';
   return this.http.post<any>(url, user).pipe(map(res => {
     this.guardStorage(res.id, res.token, res.user, res.menu);
     return true;
   }),
     catchError(error => console.log(error))
   );
}
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rxjs 6: using catchError() gives You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50972811/rxjs-6-using-catcherror-gives-you-provided-undefined-where-a-stream-was-exp)

Answer (score 0):

### Possible SOlution:-

```
  login(user: User): Observable<any>{

       let url = 'http://localhost:3000/login';
       return this.http.post(url, user).pipe(
                map(res => {
         this.guardStorage(res.id, res.token, res.user, res.menu);
           return true;
         }),
                catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
                        error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'login 
                    is..';
                    console.error("Response Error :: " + errMsg);
                    return Observable.throw(errMsg); <---- check here
                }) 
            )
    }

or,

  login(user: User): Observable<any>{    
       let url = 'http://localhost:3000/login';
       return this.http.post(url, user).pipe(
                map(this.extractData),
                catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
                        error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'login 
                    is..';
                    console.error("Response Error :: " + errMsg);
                    return Observable.throw(errMsg); <---- check here
                })
            )
    }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res;
        console.warn("Response:: " + JSON.stringify(body)); <-- check response
        return body || [];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to return an **observable** from the [catchError](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/catch.html) function

```
import {throwError } from 'rxjs';

login(user: User){

   let url = 'http://localhost:3000/login';
   return this.http.post<any>(url, user).pipe(map(res => {
     this.guardStorage(res.id, res.token, res.user, res.menu);
     return true;
   }),
     catchError(error => throwError(error))
   );
}
```